# Marshal C++ string vector to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, pinvoke

how would I return a C++ `std::vector<std::string>` to C# code?
My methods declaration (C++ side) currently Looks like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) std::vector<std::string> __cdecl Initialize(std::vector<std::string> array = {})
```

But I have no idea about how to get the `vector` or how to send it to C++.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No marshaling for C++ collections to C#. Use C++/CLI or change the `vector<>` to something else.

Comment: @xanatos alright thank you for your answer, so its only the Basic types which can be exchanged from C# to C++ and vice-versa, right?

Comment: @ThFI basic types, C-style arrays, C-style strings (char*, wchar_t*), structs composed of these things, pointers.

Comment: @xanatos thank you so much for making that clear for me :) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not trivial to marshal a `vector` of strings.

You may consider building a bridging layer between C++ and C# using C++/CLI.

If you don't want to use C++/CLI, a valid alternative is to use `SAFEARRAY`s. You can simplify safe array programming in C++ with `ATL::CComSafeArray`.

You may find [this article on safe arrays on MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795188) helpful.

You should also pay attention to the string encoding. If you use UTF-8 for you `std::string`s, then you should convert to UTF-16 for `SAFEARRAY(BSTR)` or for the .NET `String` class.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I am going to check if that works for me. Thanks also for suggesting more than one way :)